Need help with validation formula for document list in SharePoint list
I am trying to apply validation to document title column, we replacing spaces in title with dashes manually, Validation should fail if it cant find dash in title column, but only want to apply it to new items and not to existing items. So Title needs to contain "-" if that's true all good, no need to check created date, But if dash is not found it should check whether the Document [Created] date is less than today, if its less than today then all good, but if created date is equal to today then validation should fail.
This is the formula i have tried so far but it doesn't seem to work
=IF(FIND("-",Title),TRUE,IF(Created<TODAY(),TRUE,FALSE))

Validation formula in Share Point can only relate to current column and cannot involve other columns. Your formula is to check the Title column, then the formula can only appear Title, not Created column.

You can try using power apps to redesign your items' properties panel to add this validation.

